# How to store custom field in session in woo commerce checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom field in woocommerce checkout page and its a checkbox, When customer checked
this will charge them extra pay and the amount will be added to the total price.
It's all working fine but the issue I am getting is with reloading, when I reload the page it will automatically unchecked and remove the additional price from the total.
So looking for some solution on this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'add_custom_checkout_checkbox', 20 );
function add_custom_checkout_checkbox(){
    $carry_bag_label = get_field('label_carry_bag' , option);
    // Add a custom checkbox field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'installment_fee', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'label' => __($carry_bag_label),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    ), '' );
}

// Remove "(optional)" label on "Installement checkbox" field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'installment_fee' === $key && is_checkout() ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// jQuery - Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_fee_script' );
function checkout_fee_script() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    if( WC()->session->__isset('enable_fee') )
    WC()->session->__unset('enable_fee')
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
        return false;

        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=installment_fee]', function(e){
        $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_enable_fee', 'get_enable_fee' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_enable_fee', 'get_enable_fee' );

/** update cart total **/
function cabinet_sides_additional_charges( $cart_object )
{
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) )
    {
        parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
    }
    else
    {
        $post_data = $_POST;
    }
     if ( isset($post_data['installment_fee']) ) {
        $price_new = get_field('carry_bag_price', option);
        WC()->cart->add_fee('Extra Carry Bag Price Added ',$price_new, false ); 
    }
    

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','cabinet_sides_additional_charges' );

/** update cart total end **/

function get_enable_fee() {
    if ( isset($_POST['enable_fee']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('enable_fee', ($_POST['enable_fee'] ? true : false) );
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: If you want to set the checkbox checked again after a reload, then you will of course have to store the current status somewhere. But you are removing `enable_fee` from the session again, after you added the fee ... I think you will need to find a different approach here, that value needs to _stay_ in your session. (Maybe you need a _second_ value stored in the session, to determine wether you already added the fee or not, so that doesn't happen twice.)

Comment: Setting the checkbox checked when generating it with `woocommerce_form_field`, is explained here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108556